# How to write to a separate PHP file in plugin settings

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

I need a way of taking a variable from a plugin's settings and write it to a small key file located in the plugin's directory. The entire contents of the key file is this:

```
<?php
$transaction_key = "npo7d3A0d2hhTYF5w9uo";
?>
```

I've tried to use `file_put_contents`, but I can't get it to work. Anyone know how to correctly do this?

Comment: Why do you need to do this, exactly? You are always going to risk having server permissions hassles when trying to write to files, and there may be no way to solve those problems without control of the server configuration.

Comment: Currently, the transaction key is hidden in the html form. I want to change it so it's not visible by viewing the source.

Comment: You cannot rely on write access in the plugin directory, and such an information shouldn't be stored in publicly accessible files anyway. Use an option for that.

Comment: An option? What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible especially if you also need to keep the key in secret. Just use the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works. You are just not passing the right file path.

```
    $base = dirname(__FILE__); // That's the directory path
    $filename = 'key.php';
    $fileUrl = $base . '/' . $filename;
    $data = '<?php $transaction_key="'. get_option('option_name') . '"?>';
    file_put_contents($fileUrl, $data);
```